# Negation of a Statement when Logical Equivalences are Involved

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, propositional-calculus

How do we negate a statement/definition when logical equivalences are involved? For example, how do we negate

$\textbf{Definition}.$

Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $\textbf{v}_1,\dots,\textbf{v}_n \in V$. Let $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ be scalars. Let $\textbf{0}$ be the zero element of $V$.

$\textbf{v}_1,\dots,\textbf{v}_n$ are said to be linearly independent if $$\alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n = \textbf{0} \Leftrightarrow \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n = 0$$

Using this definition, how would one go about defining linear dependence by negating it?

The difficulty for me arises since $a \leftrightarrow b$ is not the same as $a \Leftrightarrow b$.

$a \Leftrightarrow b$ means $a \leftrightarrow b$ is a tautology, i.e $a$ and $b$ have the same truth value, so the bi-implication is always true.

Comment: "since $a↔b$ is not the same as $a⇔b$" ? The formula above is a *definition* and we have to read the formula with a *bi-conditional*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Do we not read it as a bi-conditional, and then assert that the bi-conditional is true? I think I am having difficulties understanding the difference between $\leftrightarrow$ and $\Leftrightarrow$.

Comment: [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) is : "two statements are equivalent if they have the same truth value in every model. Logical equivalence is different from material equivalence (i.e. the *bi-conditional*), although the two concepts are closely related."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, be careful with assuming a precise difference between $\Leftrightarrow$ and $\leftrightarrow$. While *some* authors will maintain a particular technical distinction between them, many will not -- and those who do distinguish may do so in a different way than you expect.

Second, the definition you quote is badly written. In particular, the "Let $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ be scalars" in the beginning should not be there -- saying so at that point gives the impression that you need to choose particular $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ before you can say whether the vectors are independent (and that the answer to that could depend on which scalars you choose).

Of course what is meant is really:

> Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $\textbf{v}_1,\dots,\textbf{v}_n \in V$. Let $\textbf{0}$ be the zero element of $V$.
>
> $\textbf{v}_1,\dots,\textbf{v}_n$ are said to be linearly independent if $$\forall \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n: \bigl[ \alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n = \textbf{0} \Leftrightarrow \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n = 0 \bigr]$$

The $\alpha_i$s are quantified *inside* the defining condition for "independent". This may be what you say you're understanding implicitly by the use of $\Leftrightarrow$ rather than $\leftrightarrow$, but making the quantification explicit is important when negating the definition.

The negated property would be
$$ \neg\forall \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n: \bigl[ \alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n = \textbf{0} \Leftrightarrow \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n = 0 \bigr]$$
which is the same as
$$ \exists \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n: \bigl[ \alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n = \textbf{0} \not\Leftrightarrow \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n = 0 \bigr]$$

So we should be looking for a choice of scalars such that the two sides have different truth values. Since we're talking about a vector space, if the scalars are all zero, then the combination of the left will also be, so the only way for the truth values to be different is the vector sum is zero but the scalars are not.

So *in the presence of the vector space axioms*, the negated condition is equivalent to
$$ \exists \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n: \bigl[ \alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n = \textbf{0} \land (\alpha_1\ne 0\lor \cdots\lor \alpha_n \ne 0) \bigr]$$

Comment: I wanted to avoid using $\forall$ since (forgive me if this seems really stupid) you are writing $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are all $0$, but the $\forall$ seems to consider scalars other than zero. Why is it valid to write "for all scalars" but then write "the scalars are $0$"?

Comment: @Leekboi: "The scalars are all $0$" is simply a claim that can be either true or false. The definition says that in order to consider the vectors independent, then for all choices of scalars the truth value of "the scalars are all $0$" must always _agree_ with the truth value of "the vector sum is $0$". It is fine if for some choices of scalars they are both true, and for other choices of scalars they are both false -- they just can't have _different_ truth values.

Comment: @Leekboi: And you _can't_ avoid thinking about the quantification of the $\alpha_i$ -- at least not if you want to understand the negation of the definition without resorting to pure guesswork. It is an essential part of how the definition works.

Comment: Thank you for making this crystal clear. When negating definitions and statements like these in general, it seems that $\Leftrightarrow$ and $\leftrightarrow$ behave in similar ways. For example, the final condition your arrived at for linear dependence can be obtained by simplifying $\alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n = \textbf{0} \leftrightarrow (\alpha_1 = 0 \land \dots \land \alpha_n = 0)$. Why is this?

Comment: @Leekboi: No it can't. It's not just a mater of simplifying: You need to use the vector space axioms to know that one of the directions is automatic.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $P\Leftrightarrow Q$ is the same as $(\neg P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (P \wedge Q)$, so if you negate this, you obtain
\begin{align*}\neg((\neg P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (P \wedge Q)) &= (P \vee Q) \wedge (\neg P \vee \neg Q) \\&=(P \wedge \neg P ) \vee (P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (Q\wedge \neg P) \vee (Q \wedge \neg Q) \\&=(P\wedge \neg Q) \vee (Q \wedge \neg P)
\\& = (P\wedge \neg Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q)\end{align*}

In your case this means that $$\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n = 0 ~\text{ and }~ \alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n \neq \textbf{0} $$ or $$\alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n = \textbf{0} ~\text{ and }~ \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n \neq 0$$
Since the first option is not possible ($\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n = 0$ implies $\alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n = \textbf{0}$), the negation of the equivalence is just 
$$\alpha_1 \textbf{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_n \textbf{v}_n = \textbf{0} ~\text{ and }~ \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n \neq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

The formula is a definition.

We have to read it as follows :

> > $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are said to be *linearly independent* if for every $n$-uple of scalars : $α_1,\ldots,α_n$ we have that :
>
> $$α_1v_1 + \ldots + α_nv_n = 0 ⇔ α_1=\ldots = α_n=0.$$

The correct negation will assert that for *some* $n$-uple $α_1,\ldots,α_n$ the negation of $(A ⇔ B)$ will hold.

The negation of the bi-conditional is : $\lnot (A \Rightarrow B) \lor \lnot (B \Rightarrow A)$, i.e. $(A \land \lnot B) \lor (B \land \lnot A)$.

But the case : $α_1=\ldots = α_n=0$ and $α_1v_1 + \ldots + α_nv_n \ne 0$ must be excluded.

Thus we have that :

> $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are said to be *linearly dependent* if for *some* $n$-uple $α_1,\ldots,α_n$ such that not all the $α_i$ are eqaul to $0$, we have :
>
> $$α_1v_1 + \ldots + α_nv_n = 0.$$